How to setup Windows 11 to use one laptop dedicated GPU for only one website (Onshape)?
My laptop has integrated (AMD m780) and discrete (rtx-4050) graphics.
In Windows 11 I can successfully configure apps to use whichever I like, or else let OS decide.
Iuse Onshape 3D design, which is browser-based and benefits from the discrete GPU.
But I want to use my web-browser for daily tasks on the integrated gpu for extended battery life, and only use the dedicated when i'm designing in Onshape.
Is there a way to specify discrete graphics for one website only? And avoid manually re-setting the preferred GPU every time I start and finish designing (and likely forgetting meaning I'm wasting battery sometimes and designing on weaksauce GPU at others).
I have considered having a specific browser just for high power mode, but I already use multiple browsers and don't want to lose a whole one for just Onshape. (Firefox full of plugins and cookies as general usage, Brave for YouTube and mostly untracked, Chrome with very few plugins for max compatibility.)
Mqybe there's a way to make a shortcut that invokes the GPU? i.e. if I launch Chrome normally it uses integrated, but if I launch from my shortcut it invokes the discrete and tidies up after itself?
I'm comfortable writing a little code but don't really know where to start.
